# Sendgrid Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, sendgrid

I'm using the free Sendgrid Account on Azure and I'm building a Xamarin Forms App and was wondering about the best way to send emails seeing as I can't use the Sendgrid SDK. Is it possible to send the email by manually forming the HTTP request headers? I've no code on this and I'm completely at a loss!

Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion it is bad practice to send mails directly from your app altogether. It means that you rely on your users network etc. if ports are open and even more; you expose your settings of your Sendgrid account in an app that can potentially be reverse engineered and taken out of your binary.

You should move the code to send an email to your server-side and only send a signal from your app that an email is to be sent at that time. In your server code you probably can use all the Sendgrid SDK code without a problem.